# Why do Visual Studio's AngularJS templates get embedded in a function call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio's AngularJS templates look like

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.stuff ...
})();
```

What's the point of creating a function and calling it? What's wrong with:

```
'use strict';
angular.stuff ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It entirely depends on what angular.stuff is but the general idea is to avoid polluting your scope with random globals.

It is typically called an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE), it means you can define any variables you want inside it and not have to worry about them causing issues in a separate scope because their existence will be restricted to that function.

Answer (score 1):

as bonyjoe mentioned, this practice is known as IIFE. Because javascript is Function scope not block scope and if you declare a variable without `var` keyword it will become a global variable. even though `'use strict';` doesn't allow declaration of objs without `var` keyword it is not enforced strictly. IIFE prevents un-necessary spilling of vars outside of scope. There are many other benefits of using IIFE. Checkout this article on [Benefits of IIFE](http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/)

The original term IIFE was proposed by Ben Alman in his Blog, its a good read. [Ben's Blog on IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)